Can't acces my local API server through anodroid app made using React Native Expo
Hey what could be my problem?
let's say I'm running my local API server on 192.168.0.99 and when I tested the app through Expo Go, it was successfully making requests. Once my collegue converted into an actual independent, it stopped making any requests. I tried accessing the server through browser and it faces no issue accessing it.
Also I konw I can use ngrok and establish a tunnel, but I don't want to do that.
I don't know much it's my collegue who's making the app and he uses an app called Expo before bundling it.
I tried using the browser and it can access the server with no issues, but when I use the app it doesn't do anything. Also it used to work when I was using the app through Expo GO.

This could have a lot of reasons. Could be a permission issue, could be erroneous configurations, ... Attach some debugger to your device. If requests fail, it should log some exceptions ...

EDIT: I solved the issue, the solution is add build properties into your app.json
"plugins": [
[
"expo-build-properties",
{
"android": {
"usesCleartextTraffic": true
}
}
]
]
For more information you can check this github issue - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22887
& this Expo forum - https://forums.expo.dev/t/react-native-expo-android-http-server-network-request-failed/74113/4


adb -s  reverse tcp: tcp:

Example: adb -s 1234ee reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
you can get the device id by doing

adb devices

then in the base url link paste-> http://localhost:3000
